# Avoid event fireing for both parents and children

Tags: jquery, events

I have a menu built this way:

```
ul
    li
        a
    li
        a
    li
        a
```

The problem I am having is this: When a user clicks `li a` the li-function fires as well. The `li`-function should only fire if someone clicks just the `li` (misses on the a-tag).

```
$('#stromSkjemaTabs li').children().mousedown(function () {
    $('#console').append('debug1 <br />');
});
$('#stromSkjemaTabs li').mousedown.(function () {
    $('#console').append('debug2 <br />');
});
```

Is there any way of writing this so only one of the functions fires?
When clicking the `li a` the function containing "debug1" should fire (NOT debug2 too). When clicking `li` the debug2 should fire.

I've tried every combination of children() but I can't get this to work.

Any cleaver heads out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this..

```
$('#stromSkjemaTabs li').children().mousedown(function () {
    $('#console').append('debug1 <br />');
});
```

to this

```
$('#stromSkjemaTabs > li > a').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#console').append('debug1 <br />');
});
```

previous one will fire mousedown event on all the children of li, whether it is `a` or not.